# How do you escape a '#' in a Makefile shell function so it works in both old & new make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So, you have to escape a `#` in a Makefile when using it in a `$(shell` function, like this:

```
FOO2 := $(shell echo '\#' | cat)
$(info FOO2: $(FOO2))
```

otherwise, in old `make` you get an `*** unterminated call to function 'shell': missing ')'.` error.

The above prints the following in old `make` :

```
FOO2: #
```

but it prints the following in new `make` :

```
FOO2: \#
```

which makes the semantics of the shell script different depending on the version of `make` that's being used.

But how do you do this so the variable `FOO2` gets the same value when run in old make AND new make?

Comment: the bug fix here is worse than the bug.

Comment: I suppose "don't use `$(shell)`" is not what you want to hear, though this is, in fact, good advice for portability.  `$(shell)` is a feature specific to GNU `make`. As far as I am aware, none of the other POSIX-compatible `make`s support it.

Comment: Do you know which version of GNU `make` introduced this behavior change?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm not interested in non-GNU make

Comment: @JohnBollinger not sure. somewhere between 3.82 and 4.3

Comment: I guess it's 4.3, then, because my `make` 4.2.1 exhibits the behavior you attribute to "old make".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, serious facepalm ahead:

First you have to do

```
HASH := \#
```

because apparently, while the escpaing rules for `$(shell` changed, the rules for plain variable assignment *didn't* change!

then you have to

```
FOO2 := $(shell echo '$(HASH)' | cat)
$(info FOO2: $(FOO2))
```

:facepalm:

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises with how `make` parses the line containing the invocation of the `$(shell)` function, so you should be able to fix it by altering that line to moot the question of embedded comment syntax.  I don't have an installation of `make` 4.3 handy for testing, but this works in `make` 4.2.1, and I expect it to work in `make` 4.3 as well:

```
hash = \#

FOO2 := $(shell echo '$(hash)' | cat)
$(info FOO2: $(FOO2))
```

In other words, express the troublesome content indirectly via a variable.  [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Contents.html) (still) seems to indicate that the backslash escape is appropriate in the latest `make`.  I have to assume that in 4.3, `make` is applying special treatment when parsing the `shell` function invocation, which this approach should sidestep.